# Expectation of discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

Toss a fair coin 10 times. Let N be the number of times the pattern HHHH occurs. For example, in the sequence HHHHHHT, it occurs three times. Find E{N}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a fair coin, any sequence of a given length is equally likely. We have $10 - 4 + 1 = 7$ possible sub-sequences of length $4$ and a total of $2^4 = 16$ different H T patterns; resulting in an expected value of $7/16=0.4375$

Comment: How are there $2^4$ different patterns?

Comment: HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, etc. 4 positions with 2 possibilities each => 2* 2* 2* 2 = 2^4

Comment: I don't understand how you got 7/16

Comment: Define the random variables X1, X2, ..., X7 where Xi is a random variable which takes on the value 1 if the substring i, i+1, i+2, i + 3 is equal to HHHH and 0 otherwise. Then, E[X1] = E[X2] = ... = E[7] = 1 / 2^4. The result we seek is E[X1 + X2 + ... + X7]. By linearity of expectation, this is just 7/16.

Comment: But here you are saying that N=$X_1 + ... + X_7 $
However, if you have N=2 and $X_1 = X_3 = 1 $, then you are forced to have $ X_1 $ =1 which is not possible?

Comment: E[Xi] is the expectation of having a match starting at position i; the result is  the sum of expectations of having matches at all possible (1,2,...,7) starting positions and by the linearity of expectation this is the sum of individual expectations. A simple monte-carlo simulation may help convince you.